# How to tell if folder exists and is writable?

Tags: go, directory

I'd like `func FolderExists(path string) bool` that will tell whether a folder exists and is writable. I've gotten here:

```
func FolderExists(path string) bool {
    info, err := os.Stat(path)
    return os.IsExist(err) && info.Mode().IsDir() && info.Mode().???
}
```

How to tell if this folder is writable? I cannot simply check for filemode permissions (e.g. 0200 for user write permission) because then I'd have to check the owner of the file. Is there a straightforward way to do this in Go?

For those with UNIX backgrounds, looking for the equivalent of the very simple:

```
if [ -d "$n" && -w "$n" ] ; then ... fi
```

Comment: this kind of thing can be tricky; the most robust solution is also the dumbest: try writing to the directory - if that fails assume it's not writable.

Comment: Having to modify a filesystem to check the permissions seems like an oversight to me.

Answer (score 17):

If you're writing for a Unix-y OS, you can use [`unix.Access(path string, mode uint32) error`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Access) with the constant `unix.W_OK` as the `mode`.

(Thanks to user fxxn for flagging when the `unix` package was added, and see Gautham's answer if you want to know how to write alternate code for Windows.)

Though that answers to the question as asked, you still need to check for success when you actually access the directory, and maybe that's *all* you want to do. As kostix notes, permissions could change after you do the access check, or there could be an unrelated error. Ricky Zhang says in a comment that `unix.Access` can return an outright wrong result in specific situations with NFS. If you *only* check that the actual operation succeeds, you also avoid having to fuss with platform-specific functions from the `unix` package.

An explicit access check is probably only warranted if it's especially helpful to quit *early* when a future operation is expected to fail.

Anyway, here's  code that checks for existence and access that gets me the expected result on Linux:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func writable(path string) bool {
    return unix.Access(path, unix.W_OK) == nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("/etc writable?", writable("/etc"))
    fmt.Println("/tmp writable?", writable("/tmp"))
}
```

Comment: Note that nowadays the `syscall` package shouldn't be used. It's replaced by `x/sys`, which also has an `Access` func (see [godoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Access)) and even the `W_OK` constant.

Comment: Thanks; refreshed the answer.

Comment: As a sidenote, this also works on directories to check whether you can create/delete files inside.

Comment: Right. The question text does seem to have the right scope, but the title and my answer didn't make it clear you can use `unix.Access` to check all those things. I edited the title and answer text to be clearer about it.

Comment: I found that this approach doesn't work for the case that folder is NFS mount, where UID mapping is being used.

Comment: @RickyZhang Oof, thanks, that sounds frustrating to discover. I added it as another example of why you might rely on checking the success of the operations instead of `unix.Access` when possible.

Comment: While I think this is strictly the correct answer, if you are going to write on this folder later, e.g. with `os.Open(path)`, you need also to check the executable bit of the directory, else it will error: `unix.Access(path, unix.W_OK|unix.X_OK)`

Answer (score 7):

There's no platform independent way to achieve this because checking whether the user created a directory is not possible on Windows. So, we will implement it differently for Windows and non-Windows system and then use Golang's [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) to conditionally compile the files depending upon the OS.

Create 3 .go files under directory file-perm as shown -

```
file-perm /
    file-perm.go
    is-writable.go
    is-writable_windows.go
```

**File : file-perm.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    path := "/tmp/xyz"

    fmt.Println(IsWritable(path))
}
```

**File : is-writable.go**

This builds on all platforms except Windows because syscall.Stat_t is not available on Windows. Please note that there needs to be a blank line after the build constraint **// +build !windows**

```
// +build !windows

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func IsWritable(path string) (isWritable bool, err error) {
    isWritable = false
    info, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Path doesn't exist")
        return
    }

    err = nil
    if !info.IsDir() {
        fmt.Println("Path isn't a directory")
        return
    }

    // Check if the user bit is enabled in file permission
    if info.Mode().Perm() & (1 << (uint(7))) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Write permission bit is not set on this file for user")
        return
    }

    var stat syscall.Stat_t
    if err = syscall.Stat(path, &stat); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to get stat")
        return
    }

    err = nil
    if uint32(os.Geteuid()) != stat.Uid {
        isWritable = false
        fmt.Println("User doesn't have permission to write to this directory")
        return
    }

    isWritable = true
    return
}
```

**File : is-writable_windows.go**

This file will build only on Windows because of the **_windows.go** suffix in the filename. For more info please refer to https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func IsWritable(path string) (isWritable bool, err error) {
    isWritable = false
    info, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Path doesn't exist")
        return
    }

    err = nil
    if !info.IsDir() {
        fmt.Println("Path isn't a directory")
        return
    }

    // Check if the user bit is enabled in file permission
    if info.Mode().Perm()&(1<<(uint(7))) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Write permission bit is not set on this file for user")
        return
    }

    isWritable = true
    return
}
```

> Now, you **must use** go build in file-perm directory and then run the
> executable. Please note that it won't work with go run.

Comment: First of all, `syscall` package is deprecated: callers should use the corresponding package in the golang.org/x/sys . https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#pkg-overview
Secondly, I think the `uint32(os.Geteuid()) != stat.Uid` check is wrong, because it's checking that current user is owner of that folder, not that it has write permission, that is what was needed.

Answer (score 2):

My answer won't answer your question directly but still…

In short: don't do that (unless maybe you're writing something embedded).  Explanation: filesystems are fully concurrent and hence inherently they're a subject for race conditions.  To put it simple, an sequence

1. Check a file exists.
2. If yes, read it.

Is not gonna work in real world as the file is perfectly able to disappear between (1) and (2) due to some other process deleting it.

So the only real way to write the above sequence is to drop (1) and be prepared to deal with a file open error in (2).

Returning to your problem, the only sensible way to go is to just try to create a file in the destination directory and be prepared to handle an error due to the directory being not writable.  Moreover, Go's approach to error handling is specifically tailored for such (real world) situations.

Comment: I agree you still need to be prepared for errors on write (race conditions, other kinds of error), but I think there are reasonable use cases for checking access rights first. Maybe it helps your program give a useful error message immediately, when otherwise the failed write wouldn't come until after a bunch of work has been done. (The POSIX designers apparently thought an access check separate from a wite had some use, since they specified a syscall for it.)

Comment: It perfectly makes sense to refuse starting a service for instance when you cannot write to an important directory. Instead of waiting and failing with the first request.